# Windows Server 2016でKerberos AES128ビット暗号で認証したい。

Tags: windows, windows-server, openldap, ldap, active-directory

WindowsServer2016のADにおいて、任意のユーザーにおいて以下の操作を行います。
Active Directry ユーザーとコンピューター > 任意のユーザーを選択 > プロパティ > アカウント > アカウントオプション > このアカウントでKerberos AES128ビット暗号化をサポートする　にチェック

上記ユーザーでKerberos認証を実施すると、KRB5KDC_ERR_ETYPE-NOSUPP応答となります。
AES128ビットで認証したいのですが、エラー解消方法をご存知でしょうか？
※他の暗号化方式(AES256など)で認証したい訳ではありません。

Answer (score 0):

自己解決しました。
ローカルセキュリティポリシーから「Kerberosで許可する暗号の種類を構成する」でAES128を有効とすることで認証できました。